# Can't move from a VC to another one, can't figure out why

Tags: swift

I have a register screen in my app, after the user writes done a phone number and agrees to the terms, and clicking "register" the app should move the user to the next vc. The problem is, although everything looks to be ok, the app won't move to the next screen.
This is my code:

```
    func handleRegister() {
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: USER_AGREED) == nil {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Terms and Conditions", message: "Please agree to the terms and conditions to continue", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (alert) in
            self.showTermsAndConditions()
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }else{
        guard let userPhoneNumber = self.mView.textField.text else { return }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(userPhoneNumber, forKey: USER_PHONE_NUMBER)
        let vc = Tabbar()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I tried to put a breakpoint, and it does gets to the else block when it should, and recognizes the Tabbar, but just won't move there.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible sources of trouble here.

- You are saying `self.navigationController?`. The question mark means: "If I have no `navigationController`, do nothing." If you have no `navigationController`, you do nothing. Perhaps what you meant to say is `self.present(vc, animated:true)`.
- You are saying `let vc = Tabbar()`. That is *not* an existing view controller in the interface or storyboard. So when you move there, it might be empty (that depends on how Tabbar view controller is constructed).

Comment: I think the first option is the correct one, so how can I move to the VC? is there a way to add a navigation controller to the screen?

Comment: It depends what "move" means to you. If you want to navigation in such a way that the user can come back with the back indicator in the navigation bar, that's a navigation controller. If you just want to go, modally, use `self.present`. I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Modally seems to work fine for me, this is what I want. Is it possible to change the animation to slide from the side like a navigation bar? or because it does not use navigationbar its not possible?